# Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run.doSomething is not a function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sheets, server-side

I am trying to check if the input name is already in a Google Sheet. However, I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run.doSomething is not a function.

Here is my `Index.html` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="meetingTitle" value=""> // Getting value here
    <button onclick="checkName()">Check if available</button> //Calling function is is causing the error.
    <p id=nameVerification><i>Click the button above to check availability.</i></p>

    <script>
        function checkName() {
            var toPass = document.getElementById("meetingTitle").value;
            prompt("toPass " + toPass);
            google.script.run.doSomething();
        }

        function checkNameCS(checkNameSSReturn) {
            if (checkNameSSReturn == "") {
                document.getElementById('nameVerification').innerHTML = "Already in Use: Please try with another name."
                document.getElementById("meetingTitle").value = "";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("meetingTitle").value = checkNameSSReturn;
                document.getElementById('nameVerification').innerHTML = "Meeting name available. Procced."
            }


        }

        function doSomething () {
            var nameGiven = document.getElementById("meetingTitle").value;
            var nameExists = false;
            var nameVerified = false;
            var name = nameGiven.toLowerCase();
            name = strip(name);
            prompt("name " + name);


            var spreadsheetId = ''; //Sheet id entered
            var rangeName = 'Sheet1';
            var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
            if (!values) {} else {
                for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
                    if (name == values[row][0]) {
                        nameExists = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (nameExists) {
                checkNameCS("");
                prompt("name2 " + " ");
                return;
            }

            nameVerified = true;
            prompt("name2 " + name);
            checkNameCS(name);
            return;
        }

        function strip(str) {
             return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I tried debuging it with prompts but with no success. It seems like the function do something is properly called. But the code stops working after`google.script.run.doSomething();`.

I have looked at the documentation for successhandlers but they dont solve the issue either.

Comment: ``doSomething()`` of ``google.script.run.doSomething()`` is required to be Google Apps Script. In your script, ``doSomething()`` is put in HTML (index.html). When ``google.script.run.doSomething()`` is run, ``doSomething()`` cannot be found at Google Apps Script (code.gs). By this, such error occurs. But in the script of ``doSomething()``, Javascript is used. If you put it to Google Apps Script (code.gs), please modify this.

Comment: Omg, I spent hours on this. Thanks so much! I just started learning Apps Scripts and I assumed that functions in script tag and Code.gs would have a similar effect. Clearly not! Thanks so much! Please make this an answer so I can accept this. Again, incredibly helpful! @Tanaike

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to modify your script and post it as an answer. So can you provide the information about ``prompt()``?

Comment: @Tanaike, they are like alerts. I was just using them to debug my code. You can leave them out of the actual code. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? And I think that when you also understand about [the issue of your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56303180/7108653) from the answer, it will help you understand about the specification for using Javascript with Google Apps Script. So please check both questions and answers. If my answers were not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Issue of your script:

- `doSomething()` of `google.script.run.doSomething()` is required to be Google Apps Script.

  - In your script, `doSomething()` is put in HTML (`index.html`), and a method for using Google Apps Script is included. When `google.script.run.doSomething()` is run, `doSomething()` cannot be found at Google Apps Script (`code.gs`). By this, such error occurs. And if `doSomething()` is run at HTML side, also an error occurs at `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get()`, because `Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get()` is the method of Advanced Google Services with Google Apps Script.
- If you put it to Google Apps Script (`code.gs`), Javascript which is used at the script of `doSomething()` is required to be modified.

#### Modified script:

In this modification, your script was separated to Google Apps Script (`code.gs`) and HTML (`index.html`). `var nameGiven = document.getElementById("meetingTitle").value;` and `checkNameCS(name);` are used in `index.html`.

By the way, before you run this script, please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google Services.

Google Apps Script: `code.gs`

```
function strip(str) {
  return str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}

function doSomething (nameGiven) {
  var nameExists = false;
  var nameVerified = false;
  var name = nameGiven.toLowerCase();
  name = strip(name);

  var spreadsheetId = '###'; //Sheet id entered
  var rangeName = 'Sheet1';
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(spreadsheetId, rangeName).values;
  if (values) {
      for (var row = 0; row < values.length; row++) {
          if (name == values[row][0]) {
              nameExists = true;
          }
      }
  }

  if (nameExists) {
      return "";
  }

  nameVerified = true;
  return name;
}
```

HTML: `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base target="_top">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="meetingTitle" value="">
    <button onclick="checkName()">Check if available</button>
    <p id=nameVerification><i>Click the button above to check availability.</i></p>

    <script>
        function checkName() {
            var toPass = document.getElementById("meetingTitle").value;
            prompt("toPass " + toPass);
            var nameGiven = document.getElementById("meetingTitle").value; // Added
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(checkNameCS).doSomething(nameGiven); // Modified
        }

        function checkNameCS(checkNameSSReturn) {
          console.log(checkNameSSReturn)
            if (checkNameSSReturn == "") {
                document.getElementById('nameVerification').innerHTML = "Already in Use: Please try with another name."
                document.getElementById("meetingTitle").value = "";
            } else {
                document.getElementById("meetingTitle").value = checkNameSSReturn;
                document.getElementById('nameVerification').innerHTML = "Meeting name available. Procced."
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)